# PowerShell - How can I open each PPTX in a collection?

Tags: powershell, collections, powerpoint

I am trying to extract the hyperlinks from PPTX's. I can do it with a single named pptx thus:

```
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Add-Type -AssemblyName Office
$objPPT = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.Application

$Doc = $objPPT.Presentations.Open("C:\temp\ppt2.pptx", $Null,$Null,[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse)
$Slides = $pptDoc.Slides
Foreach ($Slide in $Slides) {

    $Links = $Slide.Hyperlinks
    Foreach ($Link in $Links) {

       $array.add([pscustomobject]@{
            Text      = $Link.TextToDisplay
            HyperLink = $Link.Address
        }) | out-null
    }
}
```

But when I try to use a collection, it does not work:

```
$parentFolder = "C:\temp"
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Add-Type -AssemblyName Office
$objPPT = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.Application

$ourPPTs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $parentFolder -file -Filter *.ppt*

$ourPPTs | ForEach-Object{
    $pptDoc = $objPPT.Presentations.Open($PSItem, $Null,$Null,[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse)
$Slides = $pptDoc.Slides
Foreach ($Slide in $Slides) {
    "Slide"
    "-----"
    $Slide
    $Links = $Slide.Hyperlinks
    Foreach ($Link in $Links) {
        "Link"
        "----"
        $Link
       $array.add([pscustomobject]@{
            Text      = $Link.TextToDisplay
            HyperLink = $Link.Address
        }) | out-null
    }
}
}
```

I thought $PSItem referenced the current object in the collection. It works with word docs, but not with PPT's.

Comment: `Open($PSItem, ...)` -> `Open($PSItem.FullName, ...)`

Comment: Of course! Some days you just have brain fade! Worked like a charm, thank you.